# Multiple child projects built as modules under one pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Consider a multi-layer project in which every layer is built as a framework and has its own podspec file. Top layers are dependent on bottom layers so a top layer would have to import a bottom "Module". I have a consumer app that uses these frameworks so the pod file would look something like this:

```
pod 'FirstFramework', :path => ''
pod 'SecondFramework', :path => ''
pod 'ThirdFramework', :path => ''
```

What I would like to do is to organize the multi-layer project under one pod so that the consumer app would just need to call `pod 'AllFrameworks',: path => ''`. Behind the curtains, every layer would be built as before as a separate framework with all their dependencies and shipped under one package to the consumer app. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called Pod SubSpec.

you will have 
MyFramework, and then

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, think what you are looking for is called Pod SubSpec. I worked on a project that was similar to what you described and this is what we came up with.

you will have 
`MyFramework` as a "whole package deal", and then

```
MyFramework/First
MyFramework/Second
MyFramework/Third
```

as submodules of it, that different projects can import depending on the specific needs they have.

Being MyFramework the "main" pod, but yet retaining the possibility of other projects to be able to include just a portion of it. For Example, LayerModuleA is a dependency from your consumerApp and uses `MyFramework/First`, it's in another repo and it can be built as a standalone module and has an example app of its own

ConsumerApp/Podfile

```rb
pod 'MyFramework'
pod 'LayerModuleA'
pod 'LayerModuleB'
pod 'LayerModuleC'
```

LayerModuleA/Example/Podfile

```rb
pod 'MyFramework/First'
```

LayerModuleB/Example/Podfile

```rb
pod 'MyFramework/Second'
```

LayerModuleC/Example/Podfile

```rb
pod 'MyFramework/Third'
```

Is that what you want to achieve? If it is, you should take a look at the Cocoapods Documentation [under the subspec section](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec).